# Add class only for the element in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking for something like the affect of [this page](http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=Divi) (I'm looking for the trigger that start the animations with the scroll of the page)

Some people help me here in StackOverFlow with this code:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function(){

    if (isScrolledIntoView('.class') === true) {
        $('.class').addClass('in-view')
    }
});
```

The result can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/z3xTU/

But now I got another problem. I have a page with several DIVs, I want to animate all of them, but if I set every with ".class", this code add the "in-view" for all of they, at the same time. This trigger all the animation to start when the first div come to view, isn't what I'm looking for.

Anyone have a better idea that can help me?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: in your fiddle you have not even included more than 1 div . So its rubbish to Answer your problem,provide proper fiddle

Comment: The Fiddle is only the example of the previous code, my answer is after that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   $('.class').each(function () {
      if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
          $(this).addClass('in-view')
      }
   });
});
```

---

Loop through all your elems and pass the current context in the function `isScrolledIntoView(this)`, so here `this` is your **current elem** which is available in view.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3xTU/15/)

Comment: Oh great! It worked as I imagined in Fiddle, with test on my own code.

Comment: Work like a charm, thanks. I just had to fix some bugs because I'm using the animated.css (http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). Using "display:none;" on class and "display:inline;" on in-view didn't work, I had to update the code to use opacity 0 and 1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use different classes for the different elements or use ids.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if (isScrolledIntoView('.class1') === true) {
        $('.class1').addClass('in-view')
    }
    if (isScrolledIntoView('.class2') === true) {
        $('.class2').addClass('in-view')
    }

});
```

---

or

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if (isScrolledIntoView('#id1') === true) {
        $('#id1').addClass('in-view')
    }
    if (isScrolledIntoView('#id2') === true) {
        $('#id2').addClass('in-view')
    }

});
```

Comment: actually this answer is correct based on what ts asked